# Coverting String. Simple vs Unicode, Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am writing a script in python that is used to validate the vales of each cell in a parent table and compares to values in a look up table.

So, in the parent table I have a number of columns and each column corresponds to a lookup table for the known values that should be in each record in that particular column.

When I read in the values from the parent table, there will be many types (i.e. unicode strings, ints, floats, dates, etc)

The look up tables have the same variety of types, but when it's a string, it's a simple string, not a unicode string which forces me to convert the values to match. (i.e. if the value in the cell from the parent table is a unicode string, then I need to create a conditional sentence to test if it's unicode and then convert to simple string

```
if isinstance(row.getValue(columnname), unicode):
    x = str(row.getValue(columnname)
```

My question is, would it better to convert the unicode strings to simple strings or vice versa to match the type? Why would it be better?

If it helps, my parent table is all in access and the lookup tables are all in excel. I don't think that really matters, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: i don't know about the extended ascii codes, but for the most part, strings and unicodes hash the same - i.e. dict['astr'] points to the same element as dict[u'astr']. have you found problems just using them as is?

Comment: @Corley. Thanks for chiming in on ascii characters. That's my next challenge, as I have a look up table that contains these values that i will have to resolve. Very good point. As far as comparing strings to unicode, the test I tried was this: x = ['a','b','c','d'], r = u't', if r in x: print 'yes' else: print 'No'   The result was no.

Comment: but... in your case, the correct answer IS 'no'... i just tried this: x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. 't' in x -> False (correct). 'a' in x -> True (correct) u'a' in x -> True.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be better to decode byte strings to unicode.

Unicode data is the canonical representation; encoded bytes differ based on what encoding was used.

You always want to work with Unicode within your program, then encode back to bytes as needed to send over the network or write data to files.

Compare this to using date/time values; you'd convert those to `datetime` objects as soon as possible too. Or images; loading an image from PNG or JPG you'd want to get a representation that lets you manipulate the colours and individual pixels, something that is much harder when working with the compressed image format on disk.

Comment: Hey thanks @Martijn. Definitely food for thought and a good direction. I've just recently learned a bit about unicoding, but I'm far from and expert so I'm sure I needed a bit more understanding on how to handle these values.